# How to have the same css style as everbowl

Tags: javascript, html, css

How did Everbowl make the images and the sections like that? The images seem to be a division to each section with a 3D vibe(and at least I felt like that).

https://www.everbowl.com/#intro

the HTML is probably the source of the picture, but what do I need on the CSS to give the same style?

Thank you

Comment: parallax scrolling

Answer (score 0):

This effect is called 'parallax'. It's done by setting the image's attachment to 'fixed'. Heres how you might go about doing it...

```
img {
  background-image: url(IMAGE_LOCATION);
  height: 500px;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

W3Schools has a good guide for this effect: [Guide](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp), [Demo](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm)